# Error when using Pandas pivot_table with margins=True

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pandas

My code (from the book [Python Data Science Handbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920034919.do) (O'Reilly)):

*Full disclosure: at the time of writing, the book is still in early release, meaning that it's still unedited and in its raw form.*

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

titanic.pivot_table('survived', index='sex', columns='class')
```

The result is:

[image: Dataframe]

However, if I now try to add totals using the `margins` keyword, the following error occurs:

```
titanic.pivot_table('survived', index='sex', columns='class', margins=True)

TypeError: cannot insert an item into a CategoricalIndex that is not already an existing category
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Version info:

- Python 3.4.2
- pandas 0.16.2
- numpy 1.9.2

Comment: This looks like a bug in pandas to me.

Comment: For what it's worth, it works fine using both pandas 0.14.1 and 0.16.2 with python 2.7.10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be due to a change between pandas 0.15 and 0.16. In previous versions, the titanic dataset has this dtype:

```
In [1]: import pandas, seaborn

In [2]: pandas.__version__
'0.15.2'

In [3]: titanic = seaborn.load_dataset('titanic')

In [4]: titanic.dtypes
Out[4]: 
survived         int64
pclass           int64
sex             object
age            float64
sibsp            int64
parch            int64
fare           float64
embarked        object
class           object
who             object
adult_male        bool
deck            object
embark_town     object
alive           object
alone             bool
dtype: object
```

With the newer pandas:

```
In [1]: import pandas, seaborn

In [2]: pandas.__version__
'0.16.2'

In [3]: titanic = seaborn.load_dataset('titanic')

In [4]: titanic.dtypes
Out[4]: 
survived          int64
pclass            int64
sex              object
age             float64
sibsp             int64
parch             int64
fare            float64
embarked         object
class          category
who              object
adult_male         bool
deck           category
embark_town      object
alive            object
alone              bool
dtype: object
```

Several columns are automatically converted to categorical, which brings up this bug. The book is currently unpublished and unedited; I'll be sure to test with recent releases and fix these types of errors before publication.

For now, here is a workaround:

```
In [5]: titanic['class'] = titanic['class'].astype(object)

In [6]: titanic.pivot_table('survived', index='sex', columns='class', margins=True)
Out[6]: 
class      First    Second     Third       All
sex                                           
female  0.968085  0.921053  0.500000  0.742038
male    0.368852  0.157407  0.135447  0.188908
All     0.629630  0.472826  0.242363  0.383838
```

Edit: I submitted this as an issue to the pandas project: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10989

Answer (score 0):

pivot_tables creates a new DataFrame therefore you need a new variable
new_var = titanic.pivot_table(...)

(..., margins = True) is the mean (average) of each column and row (bool or int)

just del (..., margins = True) and use .aggfunc = sum)